# laravel get all rows using where statement

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get all row, but I have to use where statement.

This is my code:

```
if($request->city == 'all') {
    $city = 'Show all';
} else {
    $city = $request->city;
}

$listing = List::where('city', $city)->get();
```

I have to use a `where` statement. What should I write instead of `Show all`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses):

```
$listing = List::when($request->city != 'all', function ($query) use ($city) {
    $query->where('city', $city);
})
->get();
```

`when` second parameter (`closure`) will execute only if the first parameter is a `truish` expression, in your case if the `city` value is not equal to `all`.

---

##### Updated

```php
$fields = collect($request->all())
    ->filter(function (string $item) {
        return $item != 'all';
    });

$listing = List::when($fields->isNotEmpty(), function ($query) use ($fields) {
    $fields->each(function ($value, $key) use ($query) {
        $query->where($key, $value);
    });
})
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have many request.  This is very complicated, i tried but i could not do.  For example; how to do if i have one more request like $request->number_of_rooms .Also this has a  'all'  Could you explain? Thank you very much again.

Comment: @HakanGundogan can you show output of $request->all();

Comment: Of course sir:    {
city: "all",
district: "all",
property: "Sale",
number_of_rooms: "all",
}